# Don't include all @page for a certain configuration within Blazor Server app

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there anyway I can controll when to add a `@page` directive within a Blazor server app?

For example lets say I want the page `/Test` only be included within DEBUG configuration but not in release.

I've already tried specifying compilere directives with `#define` within the `.razor` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've already tried specifying compilere directives with `#define` within the `.razor` file.

And that won't work. But you can apply `#if` in a `.razor.cs` file. So you need to create the code behind file first. (type `Ctrl+.` on the @code tag)

And then:

```cs
#if DEBUG
    [RouteAttribute("/fetchdata")]
#endif
    public partial class FetchData
    { 
       ...
```

`@page("<path>")` becomes     `[RouteAttribute("<path>")]`